# Not able to add External Virtual Switch in Hyper-V to connect Android Emulator to Network

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, android-emulator, hyper-v

I am using Hyper-V to run Visual Studio emulator for android to test Xamarin android app. But emulator is not able to connect to database machine (for making database calls) on same network whereas my computer can access that database.

I have searched a lot on internet but no luck. Even I am not able to add new External Virtual Switch in hyper-v. In my network setting I can see 2 network adapters. One is my physical adapter(Ethernet) to which my computer is connected using LAN cable **(Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller)** and second one is vEthernet connected using **(Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter)**.

[image: Adapter in network setting of my computer]

Below is the screen shot of hyper-v setting pane of my kit-kat emulator.

[image]

It is showing only one switch (window phone emulator switch) not the Realtek Pci Switch. Also I am not able to add a new switch (external switch in hyper-v ) here. Button remains disabled.

Please help me to sort out this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution while reading an article for this. For External switch to be added for Hyper-V, we must have **Hyper-V Extensible Virtual Switch** in our network adapter settings as shown below:

[image]

If it is not present then you can add it from install button. It will open a popup window, select **Protocol** there as shown below.

[image]

Once it is added, now you will see External Switch option will be enabled in Hyper-V.